# ngModel always copies last item to all fields in table

Tags: angular

I have this array im trying to display in my template, somehow it will just not show correctly. if i do [value] it will give me the correct values but ofc. not bind to the array and values.

Array:

```
{"pluNo":1,"pluName":"Smirnoff 2cl","pluDepartment":"VODKA","pluPrice":2000},
{"pluNo":2,"pluName":"Smirnoff 4cl lala","pluDepartment":"VODKA","pluPrice":4000},
{"pluNo":3,"pluName":"Jack D 2cl","pluDepartment":"Whiskey","pluPrice":2200},
{"pluNo":4,"pluName":"Smirnoff 4cl","pluDepartment":"VODKA","pluPrice":4000},
{"pluNo":5,"pluName":"Rom","pluDepartment":"Rom","pluPrice":2500},
{"pluNo":6,"pluName":"Rom 4cl","pluDepartment":"Rom","pluPrice":5000}
```

Here is my tbody of my table, the PLU numbers are printing correctly, its only the other fields that are all set to the last item of my list.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of products; let i = index">
        <td scope="row">
            {{item.pluNo}}                                                                          
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.pluName" name="plu" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="" value="">                                                                  
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.pluDepartment" name="pluDepartment" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="" value="">                                                          
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="item.pluPrice" name="pluPrice" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="">                                                                   
        </td>   
        <td>
            <button (click)="deletePluItem(item)">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: All your inputs displaying (for example) the pluName have the same name. They shouldn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**All you need to do is provide different `name` to all `inputs`**

change `name="plu"` to `name="plu{{i}}"`

And check , you will get the idea about the issue , then make that change for all the inputs.

Comment: Thanks mate, that of course makes sense. and i't works.

Comment: Just going to leave this here as a word of advice:

<input [attr.name]="'x'+ idx" [(ngModel)]="val"> will NOT work. 

It will cause angular to set the last value on all inputs

Comment: @WebDever I am facing the same where last value on all inputs... how to resolve this??

Comment: sorry for the late reply. the thing is that you need to make sure that each individual input has a different name